# Get width in kilometers of Google Maps API map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I get the current width of the visible area on Google map, i have read many docs but not success? I need to get real width of visible area in kilometers.

Answer (score 4):

I think getBounds() is what you are looking for.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(event) {
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
```

You will receive a LatLngBounds object (for reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds).

This contains NortEase and SouthWest LatLng points. Using those it should be easy to get the width in kilometers using this formula. You can create 2 pairs out of LatLng points to create a NorthWest and NorthEast pair and calculate the distance between those.

```
var R = 6371000; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
    Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
    Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```

See this as an reference (http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: Of course, it's worth keeping in mind that the width in kilometers at the northern edge of the map is usually not the same as the width at the southern edge of the map. (The one exception being a map with the equator in the middle.) We don't really know the OP's requirements here: is the desired measurement the *minimum* width of the map, or the *maximum*, or the width in the middle of the map, or some other number?